# Get a column value (like id) after mysql INSERT

Tags: php, mysql, select, insert

Can I get from PHP a value back like the new id from the row I've just added to the database or should I make a SELECT to retrieve it?

```
<?php

$sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (column_1, column_2) VALUES ('hello', 'ciao')";
$res = mysql_query ($sql) or die (mysql_error ());

$sql = "SELECT column_id FROM my_table WHERE column_1 = 'hello'";
$res = mysql_query ($sql) or die (mysql_error ());

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($res);
$id = $row["column_id"];
print "my id is = $id";

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php
Selecting can be dangerous because an auto-increment often means that records may not otherwise be unique, and therefore not uniquely selectable without the id.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way of getting the id is via `mysql_insert_id()`, as others have stated. The reason for this is that you may have other inserts taking place immediately following yours, and simply requesting the last `id` is not guaranteed to return the `id` that you expected.

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tableName (col1) VALUES ('foo')");

print mysql_insert_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is builtin support for it, mysql_insert_id() or something.